# CallLog content provider returns 500 results max

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, calllog

For some reason, If I query the CallLog Content provider, I get maximum 500 results.
Also, it seems I only get results up to 1 month ago (when my devices Phone app shows me about 8 months at the moment).

I googled it, but all I found was '[Store 'CallLog.Calls' into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178310/store-calllog-calls-into-another-table)' which offers no solution.

This is my code:

```
String[] strFields = {
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
            };

            Cursor cursor = MainApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    strFields,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );

            if (cursor != null) {
                Log.d("aaa", cursor.getCount());
                ...
            }
            ...
```

I tried adding a higher limit, but nothing changed.

Does anyone know why my results are limited?

**Edit:**

After digging a little in Android code, I got to a method called [removeExpiredEntries](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/provider/CallLog.java#CallLog.Calls.removeExpiredEntries%28android.content.Context%29)() in android.provider.CallLog

```
private static void removeExpiredEntries(Context context) {
        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        resolver.delete(CONTENT_URI, "_id IN " +
                "(SELECT _id FROM calls ORDER BY " + DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
                + " LIMIT -1 OFFSET 500)", null);
}
```

Which is called every time a call is added to the log :/
This means the call log content provider can return up to 500 entries.

This leaves me with the question: how does the native phone app (in my case, Samsung's phone app) shows what seems to be thousands entries more?

Comment: Any solution for this? if you got please post the answer

Answer (score 2):

So from looking at the logs, I came to the conclusion that the content provider indeed deletes entries when having more than 500, and what the device's Phone app does is save logs by it self