# android call log retrieve just 500 record?

Tags: android, calllog

working on an android call log app , the call log of android retrieve just 500 records , is that because error in code or the OS just retrieve last 500 records .

Comment: It seems android has 500 max limit for call logs.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067406/calllog-content-provider-returns-500-results-max

However there are some docs on changing it.honestly i did not try them. http://nexus5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/get-unlimited-call-log-your-nexus-5-other-android-phone-0156942/

Comment: If you are developing a call log app then i guess you can move it to your own db so that the android call log is always less than 500 and by this you can get more than 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android limit is 500 log of calls