# Can not get last duration call time (Java / Android)

Tags: java, android

This is my code for get amount of duration call time :

```
public void getCallDuration() {

    managedCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

    Call_Duration = 0;
     while (managedCursor.moveToNext()){

        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        Call_Duration = Call_Duration + Integer.parseInt(callDuration);

     }

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSharedPreferences("OWS", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("Time_Passed", Call_Duration);
    editor.commit();

     Toast.makeText(this, ""+Call_Duration, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

But this function can not get data of last call. If I make 2 call, first call is 5s and second call is 10s, Toast only show "5s", it should be "15s". Anybody let me know what I wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: Don't parse to an `Integer`, and dont use `Strings` remember those are milliseconds

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178310/store-calllog-calls-into-another-table